# Changing the content of a division by clicking a button on the google maps infowindow in another division

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, web

I have a webpage that is divided into multiple divisions..

one division has a map using google maps api.. and there are markers on the map..
when i click on the marker, an infowindow opens up.

now i am trying to place a button on that infowindow , which on clicked should change the 
content of another division present in my html page.

i tried it with jquery using something like this

```
<script>
$("#target").click(function() {
$("#change").html("<img src='floorplans/T2_2.jpg' style='width:100%; height:90%' />");
});
</script>
```

but this works fine when the button with id as target is present on the web page.. but when i place it on the info window, it doesn't work

my google maps script that displays a button is like this:

```
function setContentString(buildingName, buildingID){
    var content=''+buildingName+' <iframe src ="http://x.x.x.x/cgi-bin/perltest.cgi?location='+buildingID+' "width="100%" hieght="100%" frameborder ="0" ></iframe></input><button type="button" id="target">click to change</button>';
return content;
}
```

can anyone help me out with this please..

update :

my webpage code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>University of Houston-EMP</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style_emp.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBybWW3YvKrvCK7SggZJwS0NbPE_Kv3aQg&sensor=true">
    </script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>



       <script type="text/javascript">

    <!-- script to load the floor plans-->
    //<script>


<!-- load floorp ends   -->


var map = null;
var mapOptions = null;
var clickIcon = null;
var shadow = null;
var infoWindow;

var building1;
var setBuildings=new Array();
function markerObject(latValue,longValue,buildingName, map){
    this.marker=new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(latValue, longValue),
                        map: map,
                        title:buildingName
                        });
}

function createStringLocation(latValue,longValue){
    var stringLocation=latValue.toString()+":"+longValue.toString();
    return stringLocation;
}

function setContentString(buildingName, buildingID){
    var content=''+buildingName+' <iframe src ="http://x.x.x.x/cgi-bin/perltest.cgi?location='+buildingID+' "width="100%" hieght="100%" frameborder ="0" ></iframe></input><button type="button" id="target">click to change</button>';
return content;
}


function buildingObject (buildingName,buildingID,latValue,longValue,areaMap){
    this.buildingID=buildingID;
    this.buildingLat=latValue;
    this.buildingLong=longValue;
    this.buildingName=buildingName;
    this.popupContent=setContentString(this.buildingName, this.buildingID);
    this.infoWindow=new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                            content: this.popupContent,
                        maxWidth: 400
                          });
    this.buildingMarker=new markerObject(this.buildingLat,this.buildingLong,this.buildingName,areaMap);
    this.location=latValue.toString()+":"+longValue.toString();
    this.setBuildingMarker=initBuildingMarker;
    this.map=areaMap;
    this.getName=getBuildingName;
    this.getID=getBuildingID;
    this.setContent=setPopupContent;
    this.getGoogleMarker=getGMarker;
    this.getInfoWindow=getInfoWin;
    this.getBuildingLocation=getLoc;
    this.setBuildingMap=setMap;
    this.createPopup=dataPopup;


}
function initBuildingMarker(){
    var marker=new markerObject();
    marker.setMarker(this.buildingLat,this.buildingLong,this.buildingName);
}

function getBuildingName(){
    return this.buildingName;
}
function getBuildingID(){
    return this.buildingID;
}
function setPopupContent (contentString){
    this.popupContent=contentString;
    this.infoWindow.setContent(this.popupContent);
}
function getGMarker(){
    return this.buildingMarker.marker;
}
function getInfoWin(){
    return this.infoWindow;
}
function getLoc(){
    return this.location;
};
function setMap(){
    var marker=this.getGoogleMarker();
    var infoWindow=this.getInfoWindow();

    var areaMap=this.map;

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {infoWindow.open(areaMap, marker);}
                     );

};
function dataPopup(desc){
    this.setContent(desc);
    var marker=this.getGoogleMarker();
    this.infoWindow.open(this.map,marker);

}
function createPopup(desc,infoWin,clickMarker) {
    infoWin.setContent(desc);
    infoWin.open(map,clickMarker);
}





function initialize() {
    var MAPFILES_URL = "http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/";
    mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(29.7211, -95.3473),
            zoom: 16,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        mapOptions);
    clickIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
        MAPFILES_URL + 'dd-start.png',
        new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
            new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            new google.maps.Point(10, 34)
        );
    shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
        MAPFILES_URL + "shadow50.png",
        new google.maps.Size(37, 34),
            new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            new google.maps.Point(10,34)
        );

building1=new buildingObject('Class and Business Building','CBB',29.721349, -95.340585,map);
building1.setBuildingMap();
setBuildings.push(building1);

building2=new buildingObject('A.D. Bruce Religion Center','ADB',29.719408, -95.345291,map);
building2.setBuildingMap();
setBuildings.push(building2);

building3=new buildingObject('Agnes Arnold Auditorium','AHA',29.722496, -95.343887,map);
building3.setBuildingMap();
setBuildings.push(building3);

building4=new buildingObject('Agnes Arnold Hall','AH',29.722206, -95.344116,map);
building4.setBuildingMap();
setBuildings.push(building4);

building5=new buildingObject('Alumni Center','ALUM',29.725874, -95.347328,map);
building5.setBuildingMap();
setBuildings.push(building5);

building6=new buildingObject('Athletic Center','ATH2',29.726187, -95.346481,map);
building6.setBuildingMap();
setBuildings.push(building6);

building7=new buildingObject('Athletics Batting Cage','BATC',29.727612, -95.346161,map);
building7.setBuildingMap();
setBuildings.push(building7);

building8=new buildingObject('Athletics Maintenance Building','AMB',29.727509, -95.345764,map);
building8.setBuildingMap();
setBuildings.push(building8);

building9=new buildingObject('Bates Law','BL',29.723936, -95.337906,map);
building9.setBuildingMap();
setBuildings.push(building9);

building10=new buildingObject('Bates Residence Hall','BH',29.718931, -95.346344,map);
building10.setBuildingMap();
setBuildings.push(building10);

building11=new buildingObject('Bayou Oaks Apartments','BOA',29.712778, -95.340736,map);
building11.setBuildingMap();
setBuildings.push(building11);

building12=new buildingObject('Biology Greenhouse','BG',29.721296, -95.344208,map);
building12.setBuildingMap();
setBuildings.push(building12);

building13=new buildingObject('Blaffer Art Museum','FA2',29.724745, -95.342804,map);
building13.setBuildingMap();
setBuildings.push(building13);

building14=new buildingObject('Burdette Keeland Jr. Design & Exploration Center','BKD',29.724739, -95.340546,map);
building14.setBuildingMap();
setBuildings.push(building14);

building15=new buildingObject('Calhoun Lofts Apartments','CLA',29.722198, -95.33857,map);
building15.setBuildingMap();
setBuildings.push(building15);

building16=new buildingObject('Cambridge Oaks Apartments','CO',29.71829, -95.350296,map);
building16.setBuildingMap();
setBuildings.push(building16);

building17=new buildingObject('Campus Recreation & Wellness Center','CRWC',29.717712, -95.338219,map);
building17.setBuildingMap();
setBuildings.push(building17);

building18=new buildingObject('Carl Lewis International Track & Field Complex','CLTF',29.72669, -95.348206,map);
building18.setBuildingMap();
setBuildings.push(building18);

building19=new buildingObject('Physical Plant Greenhouse','PHPG',29.713264, -95.348831,map);
building19.setBuildingMap();
setBuildings.push(building19);

building19=new buildingObject('College of Technology','T2',29.723358, -95.342636,map);
building19.setBuildingMap();
setBuildings.push(building20);
}

    </script>




</head>
<body onload="initialize()">

<div id='change' class='fstquad'>

floor plans and camera data

<!--<img src="UHlogo.jpg" style="width:100%; height:90%" />-->
</div>
<div id='map_canvas' class='sndquad'>

 <!--<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(".sndquad").html('<object style="width:100%; height:100%;" data="http://172.27.140.52/EmergencyPortal.php">');
    </script>
-->





</div>
<div class='trdquad'>
<button type="button" id="target">
click here
</button>
door monitoring
<img src="UHlogo.jpg" style="width:100%; height:90%" />
</div>
<script>
$("#target").click(function() {
$("#change").html("<img src='floorplans/T2_2.jpg' style='width:90%; height:90%' />");
});
</script>
<div class='fthquad'>
camera view
<img src="UHlogo.jpg" style="width:100%; height:90%" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The html in the infowindow isn't part of the DOM until the [InfoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow) has opened (the "domready" event fires)

You can use your jQuery code if you run it in an event listener on the infowindow's domready event:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow,"domready" function() {
  $("#target").click(function() {
  $("#change").html("<img src='floorplans/T2_2.jpg' style='width:100%; height:90%' />");
});
```

(assumes infowindow is a reference to the google.maps.InfoWindow in question)

Comment: i just added the entire code of my webpage.. can you look at it please